# Cassandra nodes batch start

Tags: cassandra

I was searching about Cassandra, and as I understood you have to manually start all nodes. Is there way to start cluster(all nodes) from just one machine like in Hadoop or HBase.

For example I have 5 machines with Cassandra, each has its own configuration(some are seeds for example) can I log in to first machine and type something like this "Cassandra -start-all" or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**. But you can write a script that does this. SSH into the machine and start the node, or configure Cassandra to run as a service, that way it will start up on it's own.

The CCM tool for running multiple nodes on one machine does scripting to start multiple nodes. Take a look at the [source](https://github.com/pcmanus/ccm).